# IF % is negative, show as '0'

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of values like below, the formula I have in C1 is `=+C31/D31`
If you see C5, can I show 0% instead of negative values? But the formula must be dynamic for the whole column C.

```
+---+-------+---------+-----+
|   |   A   |    B    |  C  |
+---+-------+---------+-----+
| 1 | -784  | -2,500  | 31% |
| 2 | -693  | -2,100  | 33% |
| 3 | -685  | -1,400  | 49% |
| 4 | -679  | -1,350  | 50% |
| 5 |   21  |   -450  | -5% |
+---+-------+---------+-----+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula:

```
=MAX(C5/D5,0)
```

To have the cell be blank, use:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C5),ISBLANK(D5)),"",MAX(C5/D5,0))
```

Comment: Thanks, works! To add one thing, if column B or A is blank, can we display C as blank?

Comment: See my edit, don't forget to mark the answer as correct if that is the case

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this in 2 ways.  Cell Formatting, and Formulas.

Cell-Formatting (right-click cells -> Format Cells -> Custom) would require a custom format of something like:

```
[>0]0%;\0\%
```

as the "Type" of formatting.  The down-side is that if you referenced the data in that cell, (using some sort of formula) it would still have the negative value.

The other is to use a dedicated "formula" column as cybernetic.nomad suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with look into using `=IFERROR(MAX(A1/B1,0),0)`. It is simple way to handle it which will also handle errors as well.  In the formula you could replace the final zero with something that highlights there is an error that should be reviewed.  `=IFERROR(MAX(A1/B1,0),"Review")`

```
-----------------------
|-784   | -2500 | 31%  |  
-----------------------
|-693   | -2100 | 33%  |  
-----------------------
|-685   | -1400 | 49%  |  
-----------------------
|-679   |       | Review  
-----------------------
|21     | -450  | 0%   |
-----------------------
```

---

In the example above I deleted the value from cell B4.